# How to manage different keys with c#

Tags: c#, encryption, gnupg

I used BouncyCastle with PgpCore in c# to decrypt GPG data. How to manage the multiple prive key?

For example:

file1.gpg (key1)
file2.gpg(key2)
file3.gpg(key3)

Then I have three private keys! How do I know which key to use for file1.gpg?

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg;
using PgpCore;

// Load keys
FileInfo privateKey = new FileInfo("key?.asc");
EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(privateKey, "password");

// Reference input/output files
FileInfo inputFile = new FileInfo("file2.gpg");
FileInfo decryptedFile = new FileInfo("file2.txt");

// Decrypt
PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);
await pgp.DecryptFileAsync(inputFile, decryptedFile);
```

how do I manage the keys?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: Wouldn't you just maintain a lookup table, ex. Dictionary, for which file(s) use which key?

Comment: I don't know which file was encrypted with which key, because another system encrypts the file with the public key and then sends the system, which then has to decrypt the file with the correct private key

Comment: Seems like you're missing some pretty important data there.   Sounds like a design problem because the only way you'd have is brute force without knowing which key goes with which file.

Comment: can you make me a suggestion